# Not able to access Flask Web application running inside a Docker container

Tags: python, flask, docker, gunicorn, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`  where I build a docker image that contains `ElasticSearch`, `Kibana4` and `gunicorn`

```
# gunicorn-flask                                                                                                                                                                               
FROM devdb/kibana

MAINTAINER KS <k.s@gmail.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-virtualenv gunicorn
RUN pip install -U pip 

# Setup flask application
RUN mkdir -p /deploy/app

COPY gunicorn_config.py /deploy/gunicorn_config.py
COPY app /deploy/app
COPY run_gunicorn /etc/service/gunicorn

RUN pip install -r /deploy/app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /deploy/app

EXPOSE 5000
```

The python `Flask` application and the `requirements.txt` which contains the dependencies are in a folder named `app` in the same path as the `Dockerfile`.

I also have two files `gunicorn_config.py` and `run_gunicorn` in the same path.

The contents of gunicorn_config.py is shown below.

```
    bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
    workers = 2
```

The contents of `run_gunicorn` is shown below.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /deploy/app
```

I build the docker image using

```
sudo docker build --rm -t es-kibana-gunicorn:test-10-07-15 .
```

I save the image to a tar file using

```
docker save 45a61ddf8d7e > es-kb-gunicorn-13-07-15.tar
```

where `45a61ddf8d7e` is the Image ID.

I copy it over to another server and I load the image and run the container.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                              NAMES
d62a16fcc398        45a61ddf8d7e:latest   "/sbin/my_init"     7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   determined_shockley
```

On `port 5000` it does look like my `Flask web application` started by gunicorn is listening.

If I try to do a `POST` to that webserver, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_txid.py", line 27, in <module>
    r = requests.post("http://192.168.132.125:5000", data=json_data,headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

It would be great if someone could help me figure out what is wrong here.
I can access both port 5601 `Kibana4` and port 9200 'ElasticSearch`

Comment: What are you using to post to the webserver? How does your python code look? Also: How does your run command look?

Comment: You are confident your app is running, right? Have you tried running curl from within your container (you might need to install it). `docker exec -it d62a16fcc398 bash`. I'd start from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this container on top of Boot2Docker, you need to enable the port forwarding from the "boot2docker-vm" that runs inside VirtualBox.

This link will help you to do so : [Workarounds - Port forwarding](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried Alan's workaround, but somehow the `VBoxManage` commands there failed for me.

I finally found [this one](http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/example.html) which worked:

`VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "rule_name,tcp,127.0.0.1,5000,,5000"`